# Serialize mail filter on Postfix+Maildrop

Tags: postfix

I have a Postfix server, which uses Maildrop as filter. The filters send message data into a database. At the moment I have some strange errors: some mails will be delivered, but the processing will take longer than 30 min. There is an error

```
 Command time limit exceeded:
"/usr/local/bin/maildrop -d ${USER}". Command output: maildrop: Timeout
quota exceeded.
```

which occurs on such messages. The server receives ca. 20 mails per hour, so it is not a high performance server.

I use a base script, which looks into a folder, where I have stored multiple filter scripts, which are included dynamically into the base script

This is the general filter:

```
cc "|scripts/buildfilters"
include "mailfilters/filters"
```

The `buildfilters` Shell script combines all the files `00_name`..`99_name` within the `mailfilters` directory:

```
TMPFILE=$(mktemp)
ls -1 mailfilters/* | grep "^.*/[0-9]\{2,\}_.*" | sed -e 's/^/include "/' | sed -e 's/$/"/' > $TMPFILE
mv $TMPFILE mailfilters/filters
chmod 600 mailfilters/filters
```

So it could be, that this construct has problems on parallel processing of messages. A second Maildrop process could find a damaged file `mailfilters/filters`. Is there a possibility to serialize the message processing?